# Thread Blocking the UI

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I was following an example from C# in a Nutshell. According to the text the following code is supposed to be non blocking, but I find that the form will not display until the 5 seconds have passed.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    new Thread(() => {Thread.Sleep(5000); tcs.SetResult(42); }).Start();

    Task<int> task = tcs.Task;
    MessageBox.Show(task.Result.ToString());
}
```

I have a feeling it's something to do with Thread.Sleep() and instead of putting the new Thread to sleep, it's putting the main Thread to sleep.

Why is it blocking the UI thread?

Comment: But you are using result of task right after iniating it, so it will wait till result ready ..

Comment: You should use `Task.Delay` to get a task that will be completed in X milliseconds, rather than this method that is both more work, and also creates a whole new task just to have it sit there and do nothing (which is quite expensive).

Comment: @Servy, doesn't `Task.Delay()` also return a brand new `Task` that just sits there and does nothing (albeit not on a new thread)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `Task.Delay` doesn't need to create a new thread to sit there and do nothing, no.  It uses a timer to indicate when the task should be completed.  This scales *dramatically* better and consumes *far* less resources.

Comment: @Servy, so your remark was all about the thread, as I thought. I just wanted confirmation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `Task.Result.ToString()` (in the `MessageBox.Show`) the `Task` class has a mechanism that waits for the task to be finished before actually giving you the result (as it doesn't actually have it until the `Task` finishes. Here's my proof:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    new Thread(() => {Thread.Sleep(5000); tcs.SetResult(42); }).Start();

    Task<int> task = tcs.Task;
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
    MessageBox.Show("Waited for 2.5secs on UI thread.");
    MessageBox.Show(task.Result.ToString());
}
```

You will see that it shows you the 2.5sec message box before the messagebox with 42. (in fact, 2.5 seconds before that).

What you are looking for is this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    new Thread(() => {Thread.Sleep(5000); tcs.SetResult(42); }).Start();

    Task<int> task = tcs.Task;
    task.ContinueWith(t => MessageBox.Show(t.Result.ToString()));
}
```

This will **not** freeze the UI thread.

Answer (score 11):

When you are trying to get result of task [task.Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) main thread will be blocked until task will finish it's execution (i.e. result will be available). Use `task.ContinueWith` if you don't want to wait for async operation completion:

```
Task<int> task = tcs.Task;
task.ContinueWith(t => {         
     MessageBox.Show(t.Result.ToString());
});
```

---

BTW there is nice feature in .NET 4.5 for resuming suspended operation when task is completed - async methods:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    new Thread(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); tcs.SetResult(42); }).Start();
    int result = await tcs.Task;
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}
```

This method will yield control to caller immediately after starting to wait for task result. When result will be available, method will continue execution and show message.

Actually as @Servy pointed in comments, async method which return `void` is not very good practice (e.g. for error handling), but sometimes it's OK to use them for event handlers.

Comment: Your `DoSomethingAsync` should really return a `Task`, `async void` should only be used when it absolutely needs to be, and using `Task.Delay` makes it's implementation dramatically simpler, easier, and more performant.

Comment: @Servy I think OP experimenting with TaskCompletionSource. Agree about returning Task